# Git flow branching for fixing a bug

Tags: git, git-flow

I have been using git flow for a while. I was searching for branching model for fixing issues and bugs found in the develop branch. I know we could use hotfix but it is for master branch, or quick bug fixes for the production.

Fixing a bug on development is not a feature. I could always reinitialize git flow and overwrite the default prefix branch to bug/. But it needed to reinitialize if I need to start new feature too. Is this a good practice or there is some technique to handle this?

Comment: ... I _think_ this belongs on Programmers.SE?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`git-flow-avh` is what you want

**For osx:**

- `brew uninstall git-flow #remove your current`
- `brew install git-flow-avh #add the update`

**Within project folder:**

- `git init`
- you should see amongst prompts - `Bugfix branches? [bugfix/]` which would not have been a prompt with standard `git-flow`
- start a new bugfix - `git flow bugfix start <branch name>`

Answer (score 24):

If the fix you need to apply is just a one commit fix I would just do it in develop without creating a branch, if it involves multiple commits you just use the `git flow feature` command. The software currently will do a `git merge -ff` when you finish a feature branch with only one commit, which in your logs will look the same as just a commit on develop.

If you would like to indicate in your log that this feature would be a bugfix you could just name the branch something like "bugfix-missing-parameter" or "issue-34-not-reading-file-properly"

I can see how the word feature could imply "something new" instead of "fixing" but that's just words. Should I create a new command for a fix, the code would look exactly the same as the code of `git flow feature` so I don't see any benefit in that.

**Update November 19, 2015**

Since Version 1.9.0 the gitflow AVH Edition has a bugfix command. It's the same thing as feature but the branch is prefix with bugfix instead of feature.

Comment: I'm not able to find git-flow version 1.9.0. Can you please help me to install it?

Comment: Well, I had looked into this earlier. But it installs version 1.6.1 AVH Edition. I use Ubuntu.

Comment: For Ubuntu version other than xenial, you need to do a manual install. From what you said you are using trusty.

Comment: Ok, I created a new PPA on Launchpad for git-flow AVH. https://launchpad.net/~pdoes/+archive/ubuntu/gitflow-avh It has the latest gitflow version for Ubuntu Precise, Trusty, Wily, and Xenial. I used the original Xenial package for backporting.

Comment: I've created a question for the same at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442801/how-to-install-git-flow-1-9-1-avh-in-ubuntu-14 Kindly paste your answer here so that it will help others who are looking for the same. Thank you.

Comment: @PetervanderDoes:  Could it be an idea to add the bugfix command to the wiki page there (https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/wiki) ?

Answer (score 14):

The idea of fixing a bug on the `development` branch, as opposed to [`git flow hotfix`](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-hotfix) (on `master`) is that:

- you generally fix the bug on development `HEAD` (it is just another commit which fixes some issue introduced by other commits)
- you do an hotfix on a specific version/tag of master ("`production` branch") in a dedicated branch, and you will or will not merge that hotfix back (if the hotfix is very specific to a certain version, and is no longer relevant in the subsequent releases, you won't merge it back at all)

So I don't think you need a dedicated branch / "`git flow`" operation: just make a well identified commit and push it on top of the `development` branch.

Comment: There is also a comment from the git-flow author saying exactly what you say: https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/24