# How to install git-flow 1.9.1 AVH in Ubuntu 14?

Tags: git-flow

Currently, I'm able to install git-flow using

```
apt-get install git-flow
```

But, it's always installing version 1.6.0 AVH Edition.

Please help me install 1.9.0 AVH Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new PPA on Launchpad for git-flow AVH.

http://launchpad.net/~pdoes/+archive/ubuntu/gitflow-avh

It has the latest gitflow version for Ubuntu Precise, Trusty, Wily, and Xenial. I used the original Xenial package for backporting.